# Update em tabela Sqlite através de ImageButtom Android Studio

Tags: android, sqlite3

Tenho um projeto que estou desenvolvendo no Android Studio onde utilizo um Custom Adapter, um Employee e um DatabaseHelper.

O que acontece, utilizo um banco de dados já populado que fica na pasta Assets, sendo que este é copiado para o diretório Databases do aplicativo na sua inicialização.

Tenho também um layout onde possui um campo para pesquisa. Ao fazer a pesquisa o usuário clica num botão e o Custom Adapter entra em ação para popular a ListView.

No ListView há um ImageButtom onde estou tentando implementar uma rotina onde o usuário clique sobre ele para que o item na lista possa ser gravada como favorito. Como estava fazendo isso? pegando o número da subcategoria **sub** e o valor do favorito **fav** e passando para a função **public void update(String sub, String fav)** no DatabaseHelper.

Não estava conseguindo implementar o clique do ImageButtom, o único lugar onde consegui fazer isso foi no custom adapter.

Só que agora não consigo fazer com que o dado na tabela possa receber o update, pois ao clicar no ImageButtom o aplicativo para de funcionar.

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private final static String TAG = "Database";
private final Context myContext;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "my_db.db";
public static final String SUBCATEGORIA = "sub_categ";
public static final String FAV = "fav";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
private String pathToSaveDBFile;
public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String filePath) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;
    pathToSaveDBFile = new    StringBuffer(filePath).append("/").append(DATABASE_NAME).toString();
}
public void prepareDatabase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if(dbExist) {
        int currentDBVersion = getVersionId();
        if (DATABASE_VERSION > currentDBVersion) {
            deleteDb();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    } else {
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    boolean checkDB = false;
    try {
        File file = new File(pathToSaveDBFile);
        checkDB = file.exists();
    } catch(SQLiteException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
    return checkDB;
}
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(pathToSaveDBFile);
    InputStream is = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        os.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    is.close();
    os.flush();
    os.close();
}
public void deleteDb() {
    File file = new File(pathToSaveDBFile);
    if(file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public List<Employee> getEmployees(String codigo) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(pathToSaveDBFile, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    String query = "SELECT sub_categ, descricao, descrabrev, fav FROM tab_mytabe WHERE TRIM(sub_categ) LIKE '%"+codigo+"%' OR TRIM(descricao) LIKE '%"+codigo+"%'";

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setSubcategoria(cursor.getString(0));
        employee.setDescricao(cursor.getString(1));
        employee.setDescrabrev(cursor.getString(2));
        employee.setFavorito(cursor.getString(3));
        list.add(employee);
    }
    db.close();
    return list;
}
private int getVersionId() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(pathToSaveDBFile, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    String query = "SELECT versao FROM tab_versao";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int v =  cursor.getInt(0);
    db.close();
    return v;
}
}
```

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Employee> implements View.OnClickListener{

Animation animText;
String sub;
String fav;


private ArrayList<Employee> dataSet;
Context mContext;

// View lookup cache
private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView subcategoria;
    TextView descricao;
    TextView descrabrev;
    ImageButton favorito;
}

public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<Employee> data, Context context) {
    super(context, R.layout.lista, data);
    this.dataSet = data;
    this.mContext=context;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int position=(Integer) v.getTag();
    Object object= getItem(position);
    Employee dataModel=(Employee) object;

}


private int lastPosition = -1;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    animText = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.anima_text);

    final Employee dataModel = getItem(position);

    final ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

    final View result;

    if (convertView == null) {

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista, parent, false);
        viewHolder.subcategoria = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_subcategoria);
        viewHolder.descrabrev = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_descriabreviada);
        viewHolder.descricao = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_descricao);
        viewHolder.favorito = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnFav);

        result=convertView;

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        result=convertView;
    }

    viewHolder.subcategoria.setText(dataModel.getSubcategoria());
    viewHolder.descrabrev.setText(dataModel.getDescrabrev());
    viewHolder.descricao.setText(dataModel.getDescricao());


    if (dataModel.getFavorito().equals("1")){
       viewHolder.favorito.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_fav_seleted);
    }else if (dataModel.getFavorito().equals("0")){
        viewHolder.favorito.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_fav);
    }

    viewHolder.favorito.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sub = dataModel.getSubcategoria();
            if (dataModel.getFavorito().equals("1")){
                fav = "0";
            }else if (dataModel.getFavorito().equals("0")){
                fav = "1";
            }
            viewHolder.favorito.startAnimation(animText);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
}
```

Como poderia resolver isso?

Obs. A rotina do update estava logo abaixo da função getVersionId() do DatabaseHelper, eu retirei porque não estava funcionando. A chamada para a função de update estava no viewHolder.favorito.setOnClickListener do código acima.

NX obrigado pela resposta!

Fiz as alterações no **Custom Adapter** inserindo os códigos. Ficou dessa forma:

```
...
//Ação ao clicar no ImageButtom
viewHolder.favorito.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        sub = dataModel.getSubcategoria();
        if (mOnFavoriteEmployeeListener != null) {
            boolean fav = dataModel.getFavorito().equals("1");
            mOnFavoriteEmployeeListener.onFavorite(dataModel, fav);
        }
        viewHolder.favorito.startAnimation(animText);
    }
});

return convertView;
}

//Interface criada para a ação de update do favorito
interface OnFavoriteEmployeeListener {
void onFavorite(Employee e, boolean fav);
}

private OnFavoriteEmployeeListener mOnFavoriteEmployeeListener;

public void setOnFavoriteEmployeeListener(OnFavoriteEmployeeListener l) {
mOnFavoriteEmployeeListener = l;
}
```

Mas na **Activity** não consegui enxergar onde coloco o código, pois tentei colocar mas esta matando a aplicação.

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private ListView lv;
Animation animText;
ImageView search;
EditText textsearch;
TextView vazio;
String codigo;


//Custom Adapter
ArrayList<Employee> dataModels;
ListView listView;
private static CustomAdapter adapter;
//Final Custom Adapter

DatabaseHelper dbHelper= null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


animText = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anima_text);
search = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_Search);
favoritar = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnFav);
textsearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_Search);
vazio = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewV);
vazio.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);


search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        codigo = textsearch.getText().toString();
        search.startAnimation(animText);

        if((verificaCampos(textsearch.getText().toString()) != false)) {
            dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this, getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
            try {
                dbHelper.prepareDatabase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
            //Datamodels
            List<Employee> list = dbHelper.getEmployees(codigo);
            dataModels = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i =0; i< list.size(); i++) {
                dataModels.add(list.get(i));
            }

            adapter = new CustomAdapter(dataModels, getApplicationContext());
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

            if(adapter.isEmpty()){
                vazio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else{
                vazio.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            //Fim Data Models
        }else{
            mensagem();
        }
    }
});
//Final Pesquisa
}


private boolean verificaCampos(String campo1){
return campo1.trim().length() != 0;
}

}
```

**ERRO**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: br.com.projeto, PID: 25365 Theme: themes:{default=overlay:system, iconPack:system, fontPkg:system,  com.android.systemui=overlay:system,  com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:system} java.lang.RuntimeException:  Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{br.com.projeto/br.com.projeto.MainActivity}:   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void  br.com.projeto.CustomAdapter.setOnFavoriteEmployeeListener(br.com.projeto.Cus tomAdapter$OnFavoriteEmployeeListener)' on a null object reference at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450) at  android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510) at  android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) at  android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at  android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) at  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:72 6) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) Caused by:  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void  br.com.projeto.CustomAdapter.setOnFavoriteEmployeeListener(br.com.projeto.Cus tomAdapter$OnFavoriteEmployeeListener)' on a null object reference at  br.com.projeto.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:118) at  android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) at  android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510)   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)  at  android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)  at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  at  android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)  at  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)  at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Onde estou errando?

**Após as novas alterações**

Após as alterações no código, a lógica ficou da seguinte forma:

**CustomAdapter**

```
....
 //Ação ao clicar no ImageButtom
    viewHolder.favorito.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sub = dataModel.getSubcategoria();
            if (mOnFavoriteEmployeeListener != null) {
                boolean fav = dataModel.getFavorito().equals("1");
                mOnFavoriteEmployeeListener.onFavorite(dataModel, fav);
            }
            viewHolder.favorito.startAnimation(animText);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

private OnFavoriteEmployeeListener mOnFavoriteEmployeeListener;

//Interface criada para a ação de update do favorito
interface OnFavoriteEmployeeListener {
    void onFavorite(Employee e, boolean fav);
}

public void setOnFavoriteEmployeeListener(OnFavoriteEmployeeListener l) {
    mOnFavoriteEmployeeListener = l;
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
...
adapter = new CustomAdapter(dataModels, getApplicationContext());
                adapter.setOnFavoriteEmployeeListener(new CustomAdapter.OnFavoriteEmployeeListener() {
                    public void onFavorite(Employee e, boolean fav) {
                        dbHelper.update(e.getSubcategoria(), fav ? "1" : "0");
                    }
                });
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**DatabaseHelper**

```
//Faz o update da tabela ao clicar no ImageButtom
public void update(String sub,  String fav){
    SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(pathToSaveDBFile, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    String query = "UPDATE tab_mytabe SET fav = '"+fav+"' WHERE sub_categ = '"+sub+"'";
    db.execSQL(query);
    db.close();
}
```

No entanto, não está executando nenhuma ação no banco e não mostra nenhum erro aparente.

**Problema do update do banco resolvido**

Descobri o que estava acontecendo, a parte do código na Activity estava dessa forma:

```
...
dbHelper.update(e.getSubcategoria(), fav ? "1" : "0");
...
```

Quando o ImageButtom era clicado o update acontecia normalmente só que o valor não mudava porque se o valor do campo na tabela fosse "0" ao clicar no ImageButtom o valor continuaria sendo "0", pois o valor true é 1, por isso não se via a alteração alguma. Foi só mudar de posição os números que funcionou perfeitamente. Então com a alteração ficou da seguinte forma:

```
...
dbHelper.update(e.getSubcategoria(), fav ? "0" : "1");
...
```

Comment: O app para de funcionar porque acontece algum erro. Tem como você inserir o erro na sua pergunta?

Comment: O erro está logo abaixo Ack

Comment: Edite o `onCreate` colocando onde está `setOnFavoriteEmployeeListener`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `CustomAdapter` crie uma interface que será chamada quando um `Employee` for favoritado ou não favoritado:

```
interface OnFavoriteEmployeeListener {
    void onFavorite(Employee e, boolean fav);
}
```

Um campo e um `set`:

```
private OnFavoriteEmployeeListener mOnFavoriteEmployeeListener;

public void setOnFavoriteEmployeeListener(OnFavoriteEmployeeListener l) {
    mOnFavoriteEmployeeListener = l;
}
```

E mude o `getView`:

```
viewHolder.favorito.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mOnFavoriteEmployeeListener != null) {
            boolean fav = dataModel.getFavorito().equals("1");
            mOnFavoriteEmployeeListener.onFavorite(dataModel, fav);
        }
        viewHolder.favorito.startAnimation(animText);
    }
});
```

Na activity onde instancia o `CustomAdapter`:

```
customAdapter.setOnFavoriteEmployeeListener(new OnFavoriteEmployeeListener() {
    public void onFavorite(Employee e, boolean fav) {
        databaseHelperInstance.update(e.getSubcategoria(), fav ? "1" : "0");
    }
});
```

Observe que isso depende de uma instancia de `DatabaseHelper` que provavelmente foi criado no `onCreate(Bundle)` para obter uma `ArrayList` de `Employee`.

**(Em resposta à pergunta de onde colocar o listener)**

Após a instância do adapter:

```
adapter = new CustomAdapter(dataModels, getApplicationContext());
adapter.setOnFavoriteEmployeeListener(new OnFavoriteEmployeeListener() {
    public void onFavorite(Employee e, boolean fav) {
        dbHelper.update(e.getSubcategoria(), fav ? "1" : "0");
    }
});
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Você pode perceber que no erro possui um `NullPointerException` porque `adapter` é `null`. Talvez estava definindo o listener fora do `View.OnClickListener`.

**(Edição 2)**

Ok, duas coisas:

O `SQLiteOpenHelper` é uma classe para ajudar em **abrir/criar/atualizar** o banco de dados. As verificações de existência, abrir arquivo de dados, etc que você fez, o `SQLiteOpenHelper` já faz. A seguir uma alternativa do `SQLiteOpenHelper` que aproveita essas funcionalidades comparando com algumas linhas do seu:

```
public static class NXDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String NOME_BANCO_DE_DADOS = "my_db";

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    public NXDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        // este super vai verificar se o banco de dados existe. Vai chamar o onCreate se não
        // existe. Se existir mais tem uma versão antige, vai chamar onUpgrade
        super(context, NOME_BANCO_DE_DADOS, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // onCreate só vai ser chamado quando o banco de dados não existir
        // seria o equivalente ao checkDataBase() no original

        // prepareDatabase() faz a cópia de outro banco de dados ao que parece...
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE tab_mytabe(" +
                "sub_categ TEXT," +
                "descricao TEXT," +
                "descrabrev TEXT," +
                "fav integer" +
                ");");
        // faça a cópia aqui, copyDataBase(), se precisar
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // if (dbExist) {
        switch (oldVersion) {
            // versões anteriores do banco de dados
            // if (DATABASE_VERSION > currentDBVersion)
            case 0:
                // o que mudou da primeira versão para a versão 2?
            case 1:
                // deleteDb();
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE tab_mytabe;");

                // try {
                //     copyDataBase();
                // } catch (IOException e) {
                //     Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                // }
                onCreate(db);
        }
        // }
    }

    public List<Employee> getEmployees(String codigo) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT sub_categ, descricao, descrabrev, fav" +
                " FROM tab_mytabe" +
                " WHERE TRIM(sub_categ) LIKE '%" + codigo + "%'" +
                " OR TRIM(descricao) LIKE '%" + codigo + "%'";

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();

        // só para ter certeza das posições das colunas
        final int subcat = cursor.getColumnIndex("sub_categ");
        final int descricao = cursor.getColumnIndex("descricao");
        final int descrabrev = cursor.getColumnIndex("descrabrev");
        final int fav = cursor.getColumnIndex("fav");

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Employee employee = new Employee();

            employee.setSubcategoria(cursor.getString(subcat));
            employee.setDescricao(cursor.getString(descricao));
            employee.setDescrabrev(cursor.getString(descrabrev));
            employee.setFavorito(cursor.getLong(fav) != 0);

            list.add(employee);
        }

        cursor.close(); // o cursor deve ser fechado depois do uso
        db.close();

        return list;
    }

    public void update(String subCategoria, boolean fav) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

        ContentValues campos = new ContentValues(); // é como um Bundle

        campos.put("fav", fav ? 1 : 0);

        // Equivalente:
        // UPDATE tab_mytabe SET fav="0 ou 1" WHERE sub_categ='subcategoria';
        db.update("tab_mytabe", campos, "sub_categ='" + subCategoria + '\'', null);
    }
}
```

No `onCreate` precisa ser declarado fora do `View.OnClickListener()` do `search` pois será criado uma nova instância toda vez que algo for procurado. As mudanças são poucas, como dbHelper é inicializado fora do listener, onde fica o `OnFavoriteEmployeeListener` e outros que estão comentados para comparar com o código original:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    animText = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anima_text);
    search = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_Search);
    favoritar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnFav);
    textsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_Search);
    vazio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewV);
    vazio.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    final NXDatabaseHelper dbHelper = new NXDatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);

    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            codigo = textsearch.getText().toString();
            search.startAnimation(animText);

            //if ((verificaCampos(textsearch.getText().toString()) != false)) { // Por que?
            if (verificaCampos(textsearch.getText().toString())) {
                // não é preciso do arquivo, já que SQLiteOpenHelper cria o arquivo
                dbHelper = new NXDatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                // try {
                //     dbHelper.prepareDatabase();
                // } catch (IOException e) {
                //     Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                // }
                // Datamodels
                // uma lista que é copiada para a outra e descartada em seguida...
                // List<Employee> list = dbHelper.getEmployees(codigo);
                // dataModels = new ArrayList<>();
                // for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                //     dataModels.add(list.get(i));
                // }
                dataModels = dbHelper.getEmployees(codigo);

                adapter = new CustomAdapter(dataModels, getApplicationContext());
                adapter.setOnFavoriteEmployeeListener(new OnFavoriteEmployeeListener() {
                    public void onFavorite(Employee e, boolean fav) {
                        dbHelper.update(e.getSubcategoria(), fav);
                    }
                });
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                if (adapter.isEmpty()) {
                    vazio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    vazio.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                //Fim Data Models
            } else {
                mensagem();
            }
        }
    });
    //Final Pesquisa
}
```

Como não temos o código completo do `DatabaseHelper` original, estou assumindo que as colunas não estão sendo adicionadas, ou algo assim.

Comment: Inseri os códigos como você indicou. A única alteração que tive que fazer foi no trecho:

    adapter.setOnFavoriteEmployeeListener(new OnFavoriteEmployeeListener()

Que ficou dessa forma:

    adapter.setOnFavoriteEmployeeListener(new CustomAdapter.OnFavoriteEmployeeListener(){

...

}

Pois não estava reconhecendo o OnFavoriteEmployeeListener.

Agora não travou a aplicação, no entanto não está executando nenhuma ação no banco de dados.

Comment: Nenhuma ação você se refere não chega a gravar no banco de dados? Ou o listener nem é chamado?
Mudando um pouco o assunto, leia https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html?hl=pt-br pois o `SQLiteOpenHelper` já faz um dos passos que você fez como checar se o banco de dados já existe ou não e etc.

Comment: NX1125, não faz o update no banco.

Comment: Use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` após `dbHelper.update(e.getSubcategoria(), fav)` dentro do listener. Isso fará que o `ListView` seja notificado que o adapter mudou.

Comment: NX1125, eu acabei apagando o comentário anterior, para refazê-lo, pois não ia dar tempo de editá-lo.

Certo, vou usar o adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() para fazer um refresh da listview.

Obrigado pela dica do link do developer android, realmente é bem explicativo. Eu vou ter que refazer o código do meu projeto, pois preciso melhorar muita coisa nele.

Comment: O comando notifyDataSetChanged() não funcionou. Creio que pelo fato do sistema popular o listview depois da consulta ao banco de dados. Após a consulta o banco é fechado com um db.close(). Aí acho que teria que refazer a consulta pra ver as alterações no listview.

Comment: Uma pergunta a respeito da **edição dois do código**, a criação da tabela é necessária mesmo no caso do aplicativo já possuir um banco populado, sendo que este será copiado do diretório Assets para a pasta Databases no dispositivo do usuário?

Comment: Sim. Também será necessário copiar as informações do banco de dados original se for usar o `SQLiteOpenHelper`

Comment: Eu ainda estou confuso com relação a essa questão do bando de dados. Por exemplo, o bando vai ser copiado do diretório assets para o diretório databases. Sem criar nenhuma tabela e nenhum banco de dados o aplicativo funciona normalmente, pois o banco foi copiado de um diretório para o outro. Porque há a necessidade de se criar a tabela novamente e copiar as informações? Qual é a diferença, no caso específico desse projeto, entre copiar o bando ja com os dados e cria-lo para depois copiar as informações?

Comment: Outra dúvida, no caso desse código é possível setar o onclick na própria listview considerando que o imagebuttom já está setado?

Comment: Use `SQLiteOpenHelper` se precisar. Se já possui a tabela então pode ignorar a alternativa de código.
Essa segunda pergunta seria melhor criar uma nova pergunta no SO.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas @NX1125

Comment: Seria melhor utilizar a classe AsyncTask num projeto como esse que precisa atualizar o banco de dados e mostrar a os resultados em tempo real?

Comment: Essa também seria boa fazer uma pergunta separada.

Comment: Ok. Vou fazer uma nova pergunta.